# Setting data in Cloud Firestore with Kotlin

Tags: android, list, arraylist, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have two fields in my firestore document: A number of comments which is a number and comments which is an array of objects.

Now, I want to add a new comment to a comments array in the existing document. I know that I need to create a temporary list with existing comments, then add a new comment to the end of that list, and finally, put that temporary list into firestore using Set method. My question is - how to accomplish that? I tried with the code below, but that just creates a list of list of objects but I want just list of objects.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("name of my collection")
        .document("name of particular document")
        .get().addOnSuccessListener {

            docs: DocumentSnapshot ->

            //this creates list of list of objects
                val data = listOf(docs.data!!["comments"])

                val tempOutput = data.toMutableList()
                tempOutput.add(newCommentInfo)

               //This prints list of objects
                Log.i(TAG, "${docs.data!!["comments"]}")

               //This prints list of list of objects which I don't want
                Log.i(TAG, "$tempOutput")

                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection("name of my collection")
                    .document("name of particular document")
                    .set(newCommentInfo, SetOptions.merge())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to update a single list type field in a document (it's not entirely clear from your question), it's easier to use the [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#update(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) method and tell it which field you're modifying:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("name of my collection")
    .document("name of particular document")
    .update("comments", newCommentInfo)
```

Comment: I think that won't do the job. The comments field in my document is an array of objects (it contains username, comment info, timestamp, etc). So, when a user comments something I want to add that new comment to an existing array of comments. I know that I can't simply use the Set method and pass a new comment because it will just overwrite the existing one. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think that's what my example is doing, assuming that newCommentInfo contains the entire list you want to write (which you didn't specify in your question).  In any case, just pass the entire contents of the list field that you want to update in the document.  Maybe that's `tempOutput`?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: I've just tried with update() and it's not working. It looks like my explanation skills suck :( I just want to append new commentInfo (which contains the username, info, timestamp, etc) to the end of the existing list of comments. That means that in my comments array I can have comment no1, comment no2, comment no3, etc (one user can have multiple comments). But I don't know how to append that. Set() and update() doesn't append, they just overwrite.

Comment: update() always replaces the entire field.  You have to pass the **entire** contents of the list that you would like to see in the database.  Isn't that what `tempOutput` is in your code?